# NPM: how to publish a npm module with local dependencies in a monorepo?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, package.json, monorepo

I have a monorepo architecture that can be simplified like so:

```bash
bootstrap/
├── module1/
│   └── package.json # uses "module2" package
└── module2/
    ├── global.d.ts # contains global types that module1 needs
    └── package.json
```

So, I want to publish `module1` without publishing `module2`.

Actually, the `module2` code is not embedded when publishing. When I copy the files somewhere, I have a conflict because the global type file is defined twice.

Is there a way for `npm` to handle that? Or any workaround?